# Add all members of one class to another class

Tags: jquery

Using JQuery, is it possible to add all members of one class to another class? Here, I'm trying to add all members of the class `ui-widget-content` to the class `draggable`.

http://jsfiddle.net/j8czR/

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Draggable - Auto-scroll</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <style>
    #draggable, #draggable2, #draggable3 { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
       $(".draggable").draggable({ scroll: true });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Scroll set to true, default settings</p>
</div>

<div style="height: 5000px; width: 1px;"></div>


</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.. classnames don't have members...

Comment: @KevinB By "members", I meant "elements that have a specific class attribute" - is it incorrect to refer to HTML elements with a specific class as "members of a class"?

Comment: Maybe, but it's confusing because a Class can refer to something completely different than what you are referring to.

Comment: Look at it this way. The class doesn't contain elements, the elements contain classes. What you were looking to do is add one class to an element that has this other class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method to add the specified class..

```
$('.ui-widget-content').addClass('draggable');
```

If you want to add the class to the specified div's based on id's you can do it this way

```
$("#draggable,#draggable2,#draggable3").addClass("draggable");
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/j8czR/1/)**

Comment: What's confusing is... What he's currently doing already does this.

Comment: @KevinB .. Yes true.. But he seems to be adding just for the id currently .. And he wants to do the same for the other 2 as well..

Comment: I answered my own question just one second before this answer was posted. :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears that it's possible to do this using the `addClass( classname )` method, as described here: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/